# When Should I Disable Transitive References in C#?

Tags: c#, csproj, transitive-dependency

Let's say that I have the following projects:

**Project A**

**Project B** - References *Project A*

**Project C** - References *Project B*

If I set `<DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>true</DisableTransitiveProjectReferences>` in **Project C**'s .csproj, Project C will not compile since **Project A** is not explicitly references by **Project C**. If I do not set this `DisableTransitiveProjectReferences` flag, it will compile. It seems like when I disable transitive references I'm being very "strict" on my project.

I've seen a lot of posts online about *how* to disable transitive references but now many on *why* I should or should not.

When should I explicitly disable transitive references in a C# project? What are the tradeoffs (benefits and costs) I'm implicitly taking on in my project when I choose to keep transitive references?

Comment: This is generally used to hide away a lower layer of your solution so the developer doesn't accidentally start using things they shouldn't. However, it's an opinion based question so not really a good fit for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG Okay, I thought there might be a more concrete black-and-white answer here. How does disabling transitive references lead to "hiding" though?

Comment: Let's say Project A contains all you database logic and entities, you can prevent accidental use of the entities in Project C which might be your web layer for example, it is good practice to keep those things absolutely separate.

Comment: FWIW I don't think this is a bad question (wasn't me that downvoted), in fact I think it's a good one to ask, just not on here.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it is a good question. I agree that it's _opinion-ish_, but, saying what that does and enumerating the pros and cons is, I think, appropriate for this site. There are a lot more opinion-like questions with high vote counts here

Comment: @DavidG ProjectA's public database-related classes will still be available for use in ProjectC though (through ProjectB). That's where my confusion lies, I do not see what is being hidden. by not referencing ProjectA in ProjectC.

Comment: Yes, and project B should be able to use those classes, usually as an interface between the database and the presentation layer for example. But Project C should never see A.

Comment: @DavidG When you say "Never see", I'm assuming you mean classes in Project A should never be explicitly used in Project C. They may be implicitly used through Project B, though. Is this a correct interpretation of what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean